# Perforce Trigger, Format on Commit (change-content trigger)

Tags: triggers, submit, perforce

I'm trying to implement a Perforce change-content trigger that will use clang-format to see if files have been properly formatted that are submitted to the Perforce Depot and will send them to a new change-list with a message indicating the need to format file.
I'm not fully confident that it is even possible. My script works great from the command line (I use p4 change to create a new CL, p4 reopen so send desired files there, and p4 change -d to delete it if left empty), but the only time I was able to create a change list from the trigger call was when I included a p4 submit to the script (which recursively created 3500+ change-lists). Does anyone know if it is possible to create a change-list from the change-content trigger?

Comment: Creating a new changelist from a change trigger doesn't make a lot of sense IMO -- why not just reject the changelist (return non-zero from the trigger) if the files aren't formatted correctly?

Comment: The idea would be that it would submit all the files that were formatted and reject the ones that aren't (into a new changelist). The original idea was to force-format all the files on submit with a trigger but that seems even less feasible.

Comment: Perforce submits are designed to be atomic; letting some files through and rejecting the others would defeat the purpose of atomic changelists, so the server will deafult to failing a submit if anything (including a trigger) tries to modify the changelist mid-flight.  I'd suggest just rejecting the entire changelist and making sure the user has an easy way to fix the unformatted files.

Comment: That seems like sound advice, thanks!